# Unusually clean 5 kHz noise from BLDC motor

Tags: motor, filter, noise, brushless-dc-motor

[image]

The noise does seem to pulsate but I'm not sure how I'd go about measuring the beat frequency.

I'm driving this thing with 2 L293D (works fine with just one, heats up a bit though,) and feeding a sinewave in the form of a PWM (with frequency 32k hertz) phased 120 degrees apart.

The code I'm using is this:

https://github.com/juanpablocanguro/BRUSHLESS-MOTORS/blob/master/open_loop_youtube.ino

This user seems to have hit a similar problem:

[Noise in BLDC motor with 32kHz PWM](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/399817/noise-in-bldc-motor-with-32khz-pwm)

I have two questions now:

- Where's the noise coming from?
- What can I do to get rid of it?

Since the frequency is so consistent I thought of using a simple passive filter, but I'm not sure of the coil inductance and I have no means of measuring it. Is knowing the coil resistance enough to make some kind of filter? I wonder if I can impliment some LR high pass filter.

I also checked my power supply, it seems to be droning around 1.5kHz, nothing around 5kHz.

Changing PWM frequency seems to add more harmonics but the peak is still 5khz, perhaps this is a hardware related?

Comment: Do you hear it, or are you measuring it electrically somewhere in the driver circuit, or both?

Comment: @JRE I'm measuring using an app on my phone, i don't have an oscope unfortunately

Comment: So, it is a **sound** you are hearing.  It may not exist electrically at all.

Comment: "*The noise does seem to pulsate but I'm not sure how I'd go about measuring the beat frequency.*" : With sufficient number of sample points, beat frequency will be seen as side bands to the main frequency. Usually you will see two peaks in the fft symmetrically about the *carrier* frequency.

Comment: 5kHz might the resonant frequency of the mechanical system. Try running the motor at a different speed. You can also try a [tap test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_testing) when the motor is OFF.

Comment: Try different motor speeds and PWM frequency. Does that change the noise frequency? Check if you have an interrupt running at a subharmonic of 5kHz in the code, then change its frequency, does it change the noise? Examine power supply rails with a scope, examine motor signals with a scope, etc.

Comment: it may be an effect similar to an air raid siren